# What glue used here?

Tags: pcb, electrical, glue

What glue is it? Is it safe for attaching? 
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Where did that board come from? Why are you asking about the glue? What kind of safety are you talking about? How can we tell anything about it other than it is "white glue?"

Comment: Hi sorry for not clarifying. I got that board image from google search. I am asking about the glue cause I need to use that same glue for securing the cable support if solder fails for my project. I am not sure if it is epoxy or silicon. Thanks

Comment: OK. I recommend you use something specifically marketed for use in electronics. Some silicon adhesives may contain corrosive chemicals to help cure (this type of silicon will smell like vinegar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its probably an RTV Silicone like Silastic. It comes in various forms but RTV Silicone is the generic name.

Comment: Need to make sure it's a 'neutral cure' silicone too. Even some RTV types release acetic acid while curing.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is first soldered and then basically any glue that  is very viscous can be used ie it does not flow.

It is there to provide support to the wire and board so the soldered connection does not fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it epoxy or silicon glue?

Comment: Any glue that they have that is viscous..... and will stick to both surfaces : cable and pcb...

Comment: You want something more like silicon. Epoxy is too rigid. The purpose of that glue is to provide strain relief so the wire strands don't break at the solder joint. Epoxy will probably work, but then the strands may break at the epoxy joint. The point is to avoid sharp bends in the wire strands.

Comment: Also, you want to avoid using anything that is conductive or that may cause corrosion on the PCB.

Comment: Back in the day, the cable would have been tied to a post provided on the board - but that was a more expensive solution...